# Iteration over a Set

Tags: java, groovy, set

I'm having issues with getting an iteration done (and modification) through the `Set`, which contains Objects. I've tried so many ways of iteration (4), but none of them seem to work and still throw me the Error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

[Code is written in Groovy]

```
private void replaceRock() {
    ObjectNodeManager.OBJECTS.each {
        System.out.println("Going...");
        if(it.getPosition().withinDistance(player.getPosition(), 30)) {
            System.out.println("Found...");
            Position position = it.getPosition();
            ObjectNode newRock = new ObjectNode(439, position, ObjectDirection.NORTH, ObjectType.DEFAULT);
            ObjectNodeManager.unregister(it);
            ObjectNodeManager.register(newRock);
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried synchronization to prevent access from other Threads, but this also didn't work. Please help me, I'm very desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find them (this will give you basically a list of refs) and then deal with them:

```
ObjectNodeManager.OBJECTS.findAll {
    it.getPosition().withinDistance(player.getPosition(), 30))
}.each{
    ObjectNode newRock = new ObjectNode(439, it.position, ObjectDirection.NORTH, ObjectType.DEFAULT)
    ObjectNodeManager.unregister(it)
    ObjectNodeManager.register(newRock)
    it.remove()
}
```

On a random site note: i'd add a `replace` method in the `ObjectNodeManager` to combine unregister, register, remove.  Also working with class methods and properties is not the best thing to do (but since it looks like a game...)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: Edit: I have a small problem, what if I want two statements before going for each? Like another statement beside `it.getPosition().withinDistance(player.getPosition(), 30))` I've tried that by using the `||` operator, but that just throws me another `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: the part in the closure of findAll has to return a boolean.  so by adding something else via `||` is fine.  if the check you have added there influences OBJECT itself again, then that would explain it. maybe you fallen in a trap, where your "returns-boolean-and-looks-persistent"-function there has some sideeffects?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the list of objects while you are looping through the objects.

Try iterating through a copy of the objects instead.

```
ArrayList<YourType> copy = new ArrayList<YourType>(ObjectNodeManager.OBJECTS);
copy.each(...)
```

Comment: The problem is, that I gotta edit the SET itself, A copy of the set wouldn't benefit me at all, in terms of programming of course.